# Problem in alignment of website in Internet Explorer 

Tags: css

I am making a website using simple HTML/CSS but my website's alignment (demo) http://bookmyshirt.co.cc/help/index.html is working fine in firefox but its alignment in internet explorer is very bad.Please help me to rectify my this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using

```
#maincontainer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
}
```

which often does not work with IE. Try this this instead:

```
#maincontainer {
    width: 960px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 50%;
    left: -480px;
}
```

If this doesn't work, you could try *absolute* instead of *relative* positionning, in which case you would have to set the *top* property.

(NB: this is just *one* option among a lot of other ones)